# How can I lead a user to another site after login?

Tags: php, authentication

I know that there are a lot of tutorials about making a login system.
But strangely my code does not work.

It definetely works until password_verify.

Here is my index.php (For login)

```
<form id="sign-in" method="post">
            <input id="input" type="text" name="name" tabindex="1" placeholder="Benutzername" required><br>
            <input id="input" type="password" name="password"  tabindex="2" placeholder="Passwort" required><br>
            <input id="input" class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Einloggen"><br>
            <a href="accounts/account-not-found" id="account-not-found">Account wurde nicht gefunden?</a>
      </form>
      <?php

      if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        require("mysql.php");
        $stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE USERNAME = :user"); //USERNAME CHECK
        $stmt->bindParam(":user", $_POST["name"]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        if($count == 1){
          // USERNAME IST Frei
          $row = $stmt->fetch();
          if(password_verify($_POST["password"], $row["PASSWORD"])){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["name"] = $row["USERNAME"];
            header("Location: internal-area/home/");
          }
          else{
            echo "Das Passwort ist falsch"; //GERMAN for Password is wrong
          }
        }
        else{
          echo "Der Login ist fehlgeschlagen"; //GERMAN for Login has failed
        }
      }
       ?>
```

My "internal-area/home/index.php":

```
    <?php

  session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSON["name"])){
    header("Location: ../../"); // ../../ leads to my index.php for login (see above)
    exit;
  }

 ?>
```

I hope you can help me.
If there is any information missing, please tell me :)

Daniel.

Comment: I thinkt it doesn't work beacause of `if(!isset($_SESSON["name"])){
    header("Location: ../../"); // ../../ leads to my index.php for login (see above)
    exit;
  } `              
                  
But I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I misspelled

```
if(!isset($_SESSON["name"])){
    header("Location: ../../"); // ../../ leads to my index.php for login (see above)
    exit;
  }
```

It has to be $_SESS**I**ON["name"]